# Rate Limiting with python

Tags: python, python-requests, rate-limiting

I get some data using the requests library. When this function is scaled in the future, I do not want to encounter problems with the API, so I am thinking of applying rate limiting, but there is no value for the rate limit in the response headers of the endpoint I use, how can I control it?

Comment: Common way to rate limiting is "Ask forgiveness".
For example, API bring in limits like 10 requests in 1 minute
After you reaching limits you get error from API, then just wait 60 seconds and request it again.

Comment: @VictorErmakov So are you telling me to repeat until I get a mistake and come up with a solution for it?

Comment: Usually Rate Limiting is written in documentation. If there is no limits then yes... just try  to get limits. What other way to get this information?